# name my cat: regular categories where inverse images also have right adjoint

Tags: ct.category-theory, lo.logic

I need a name for a regular category where the inverse image maps have right adjoints.

If $\mathcal C$ is a regular category, then the poset of subobjects $\mathsf{Sub}(X)$ of any object $X$ is a semilattice and the inverse image map of any arrow $f:X\to Y$ has a left adjoint $\exists_f:\mathsf{Sub}(X) \to \mathsf{Sub}(Y)$. If $\mathcal C$ is a Heyting category, then the inverse image map $f$ also has a right adjoint $\forall_f:\mathsf{Sub}(X) \to \mathsf{Sub}(Y)$. But Heyting categories also have all finite coproducts and I want a name for regular categories that just have those right adjoints.

Do you know if this category of categories already has a name? Can you suggest a name?

Update: Heyting categories or logoses need not have all finite coproducts, but posets of subobjects are lattices, where I only need semilattices.

Comment: Is there a name for the fragment of logic containing only $\wedge$, $\exists$, $\Rightarrow$, and $\forall$?  If so, you could borrow the same name for your categories, since it would probably be their internal logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Freyd and Scedrov's book *Categories, Allegories*: a **logos** is a regular category in which $Sub(A)$ is a lattice for each object $A$, and in which the inverse-image operation $f^*: Sub(B) \to Sub(A)$ has a right adjoint for each morphism $f: A \to B$ (page 117).

Comment: I don't want a lattice structure on my subobject posets. But maybe I could call my categories "hemilogoses" or something like that.

Comment: Sorry I don't know a name for precisely what you want. It seems like a natural-enough notion. 